# date format in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

in my database i stored date in the format "yyyy-mm-dd" i need to compare the stored dates with the current date. But How can i get the current date in the above format in asp.net.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you provide a few more details in regards to your question. Where do you want to compared these dates? Server-side or client side? What's the use of the comparison?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider converting that date field in your database schema to a "datetime" data type. That will make it easier to do operations with this value (e.g. equality, greater than, less than, addition, subtraction etc...).

Answer (score 1):

```
if (DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd").Equals(myDateString))
{
    //Do my thing here
}
```